# How to use JOIN , ORDER BY and WHERE in php at same time

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "SELECT feed.feed_id, feed.title, feed.imgsrc, feed.details, Author.author_name, Feed_class.class_name, feed.create_at \n"

. "    FROM feed JOIN Author JOIN Feed_class \n"

. "    ON feed.author_id = Author.author_id AND feed.feedClass_id = \n"

. "    Feed_class.feedClass_id ORDER BY feed.create_at WHERE feed_id = $feed_id; ";
```

Comment: Is there a specific problem? Please don't just dump code with no proper explanation or context. See [ask] and how to create a [mre] for more guidance on asking a useful question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT feed.feed_id, feed.title, feed.imgsrc, feed.details, Author.author_name, Feed_class.class_name, feed.create_at \n"

. "    FROM feed JOIN Author ON feed.author_id = Author.author_id  \n"

. "     JOIN Feed_class ON feed.feedClass_id = \n"

. "    Feed_class.feedClass_id WHERE feed_id = $feed_id ORDER BY feed.create_at ; ";
```

> two issues noted: 1. location of ON clause:- it should be after
> mentioning the second table of the join
>
> FROM feed JOIN Author ON feed.author_id = Author.author_id
> JOIN Feed_class ON feed.feedClass_id = Feed_class.feedClass_id

2. Issue two was on Order of WHERE Clause and ORDER Clause:- WHERE appears before ORDER

> WHERE feed_id = $feed_id ORDER BY feed.create_at